# Excel Parsing String in Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to parse a string column in my Excel file.

The column looks like this:

```
ABC for XYZ123 at ABC
ABC for SUJ132 at DCB
DCE for UEJ958 at PLD
```

I want to create a formula that parses everything after "for" and before "at".

Expected Result:

```
XYZ123
SUJ132
UEJ958
```

I have this formula: `=MID(A2,(FIND("for",A2,1)+4),FIND("at",A2,2))`
But this is resulting in:

```
XYZ123 at ABC
SUJ132 at DCB
UEJ958 at PLD
```

Any help?

Comment: `=MID(A2,(FIND("for",A2,1)+4),5)`. If the string to extract is of variable length, then `=MID(A2,(FIND("for",A2,1)+4),FIND("at",A2,2)-FIND("for",A2,1)-5)`

Comment: `=MID(A2,(FIND("for",A2,1)+4),LEN(A2)-FIND("at",A2,2)-1)` would also work

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("for ",A2)+4,FIND(" at",A2)-FIND("for ",A2)-4)
```

`FIND("for ",A2)+4` specifies the starting position, and `FIND(" at",A2)-FIND("for ",A2)-4` identifies the number of characters between.

Answer (score 0):

=MID(A2,(FIND("for",A2,1)+4),5). If the string to extract is of variable length, then =MID(A2,(FIND("for",A2,1)+4),FIND("at",A2,2)-FIND("for",A2,1)-5)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Excel 2013+, you can also use the `FILTERXML` function:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[preceding::*='for' and following::*='at']")
```

[image]